# why is my website throwing me Authentication Mode=windows error

Tags: c#, asp.net, publishing

When I load my web page its giving me this error, I just published it from visual studio, where it was function perfectly fine and now its giving me an error.

> Configuration Error
>
> Description: An error occurred during the processing of a
>   configuration file required to service this request. Please review the
>   specific error details below and modify your configuration file
>   appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: It is an error to use a section registered as
>   allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This
>   error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an
>   application in IIS.
>
> Source Error:
>
> ```
> Line 87:             ASP.NET to identify an incoming user. 
> Line 88:         -->
> Line 89:      <authentication mode="Windows"/>
> Line 90:      <!--
> Line 91:             The <customErrors> section enables configuration
> ```

Comment: Make sure you have all your dependency `dll` and `Files`in your published project folder. In other way Deploy the app and check with local `IIS`  in `DEBUG` mode.

Comment: Apparently I was unfamiliar with publishing the pages. I come from php background, so i just kinda moved the files to the server.  My manager corrected me and showed me the proper method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Whenever a new web application created, using Visual Studio.net it automatically creates a virtual directory in IIS and configures as an application. So you have to manually create a Virtual directory and configure it to application.

**Start->All program-mes->Administrative tools->Internet Information service-> Select Server name->Web Site->Default Web site-> right click ->new->virtual directory**

this opens a virtual directory wizard. give a name, give path of application. Give appropriate permission. then Finish.

Now to cross check whether its configured to an application or not, **select created virtual directory Right click->properties->Select Virtual directory under "Application settings"**

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robgruen/archive/2005/09/12/464196.aspx

Answer (score -2):

delete all code in web.config and paste

```c#
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration>

  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="your connection string name" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\your database name;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
  </system.web>

</configuration>
```

it will work.

Comment: @SimonH, had you actually investigated this answer, rather than racing through the review, you would have seen that editing this answer would have been the correct choice. SO's templating hid half this user's actual answer.